# Qooxdoo Remote table getRowCount() return 0

Tags: qooxdoo

```
    qx.Class.define("webApp.backendjs.tables.RegionesModel", {
        extend: qx.ui.table.model.Remote,
        members: {
            _loadRowCount: function () {
                var params = {};
                params.action = "getCount";
                var rpc = new qx.io.remote.Rpc("http://qx.alpali.cl/svc/svc.php");
                rpc.setProtocol("2.0");
                rpc.setCrossDomain(true);
                rpc.callAsync(qx.lang.Function.bind(this._onRowCountCompleted, this), "regiones.regiones.getNominaRegiones", params);
            },

            _onRowCountCompleted: function (result, exc) {
                if (result !== null) {
                    this._onRowCountLoaded(result.count);
                }
            },

            _loadRowData: function (firstRow, lastRow) {
                var params = {};
                params.action = "getData";
                var rpc = new qx.io.remote.Rpc("http://qx.alpali.cl/svc/svc.php");
                rpc.setProtocol("2.0");
                rpc.setCrossDomain(true);
                rpc.callAsync(qx.lang.Function.bind(this._onLoadRowDataCompleted, this), "regiones.regiones.getNominaRegiones", params);
            },

            _onLoadRowDataCompleted: function (result, exc) {
                if (result !== null) {
                    this._onRowDataLoaded(result);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var RTRegionesModel = new webApp.backendjs.tables.RegionesModel();
    RTRegionesModel.setColumns(["ID", "C贸digo", "Nombre"], ["id", "region_id", "region_nombre"]);

    var TableRegiones = new qx.ui.table.Table(RTRegionesModel);
    TableRegiones.setTableModel(RTRegionesModel);

    // THIS don't work, return 0
    TableRegiones.addListener('appear', function () {
        console.log("RTRegionesModel.getRowCount(): %s", RTRegionesModel.getRowCount());
    }, RTRegionesModel);

    // THIS don't work, return 0
    TableRegiones.addListener('appear', function () {
        console.log("RTRegionesModel.getRowCount(): %s", RTRegionesModel.getRowCount());
    }, this);

    this.getRoot().add(TableRegiones);

    var button1 = new qx.ui.form.Button("How many record...", "icon/22/apps/internet-web-browser.png");
    this.getRoot().add(button1,{right:50,top:50});

    // this is ok, return teh value
    button1.addListener("execute", function(e) {
      console.log("RTRegionesModel.getRowCount(): %s", RTRegionesModel.getRowCount());
    });
```

url for testing playground

i need the valor when remote table is loaded

what is the problem..???

thank.

PD: sorry for my bad and ugly english, my native language is spanish (chile), my best friend in this moment is googol

Answer (score 1):

At the time that you are looking for the row count with your "THIS don't work" comment, the row count is not yet available because the network operation to retrieve the row count from the server has not yet been issued.

You probably want to be listening for the model's `dataChanged` event which is fired when a row count is loaded, or when the model data changes, such as this:

```
TableRegiones.getTableModel().addListener(
  'dataChanged',
  function ()
  {
    console.log(
      "dataChanged: RTRegionesModel.getRowCount(): %s",
      RTRegionesModel.getRowCount());
  },
  RTRegionesModel);
```